# childnodes from read XML not working inside JQuery calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I read an XML I got from an API, I do this call:

```
titol=datax.getElementsByTagName("title");
```

Now I have all the titles from the XML, then I need to pass this information inside a getJSON call which I call once per title, so like this:

```
llargada=datax.getElementsByTagName("title").length;
for(y=0; y<llargada; y++){
    $.getJSON("http://bla bla bla", function(data) {
        console.log("titls: "+titol[y].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    });
}
```

But I get this error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined**

I'm using jquery.min.js if relevant...

Comment: You've added `length` which returns a number, and a number has no childnodes? Also, none of the variable names seems to match ... anything ?

Comment: So what if the variable names don't match? I'm not native english, I program I make the variables in my language. Also the length thing is only for the loop

Comment: What I meant was that you're iterating over `llargada` but you're getting the data from `titol`, those are two different things, they don't match, and the length of both arrays are not the same, so you're getting `undefined`

Comment: They are the same length. `llargada` is the length of the array which means the number of elements which are the number of titles I have. I have 5 titles and when I print llargada it's 5.

Comment: But `titol` is not `llargada`, and it clearly doesn't match

Comment: And even if did, it's in an async callback, which I didn't notice at first, but that's probably the issue, give me a second to whip something up.

Comment: Try this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/7peygjtp/**